# Convert Pandas column into same date time format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file where the date and time are in mixed formats as per below:

```
Ref_ID    Date_Time
5.645217e 2020-12-02 16:23:15
5.587422e 2019-02-25 18:33:24
```

What I'm trying to do is convert the dates into a standard format so that I can further analyse my dataset.

Expected Outcome:

```
Ref_ID    Date_Time
5.645217e 2020-02-12 16:23:15
5.587422e 2019-02-25 18:33:24
```

So far I've tried a few things like Pandas to_datetime conversion and converting the date using strptime but none has worked so far.

```
# Did not work
data["Date_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date_Time"], errors="coerce")

# Also Did not work
data["Date_Time"] = data["Date_Time"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y'))
```

I've also searched this site for a solution but haven't found one yet.

Comment: You mean some dates are YYYYMMDD and some are YYYYDDMM mixed together? How do you imagine your code would be able to determine if 20200212 was MMDD or DDMM?

Comment: Yes that's the part that I'm having trouble with, differentiating between where the dates are MMDD or DDMM, is there any code I could use to solve the problem?

Comment: Only possible way to revognize if format has days first or months first, is when day is bigger than 12, other than that it is lucky shot. Maybe you should focus on, where from data is collected, and if it may be collected again with proper format.

Comment: What @w8eight said. You might be able to do this if your data is sorted by date, but if it isn't, you might just be randomly changing some already valid dates whatever algorithm you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

you could try uisng `str.split` to extract the day and month and use some boolean testing:

this may be a bit confusing with all the variables but all we are doing is creating new series and dataframes to manipulate the variables, those being the day and month of your original date-time column

```
# create new dataframe with time split by space so date and time are split
s = df['Date_Time'].str.split('\s',expand=True)

# split date into its own series
m = s[0].str.split('-',expand=True).astype(int)

#use conditional logic to figure out column is the month or day.
m['possible_month'] = np.where(m[1].ge(12),m[2],m[1])
m['possible_day'] = np.where(m[1].ge(12),m[1],m[2])

#concat this back into your first split to re-create a proper datetime.
s[0] = m[0].astype(str).str.cat([m['possible_month'].astype(str),
                                 m['possible_day'].astype(str)],'-')


df['fixed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(s[0].str.cat(s[1].astype(str),' ')
                                  ,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

---

```
print(df)

       Ref_ID            Date_Time          fixed_date
0  5.645217e   2020-12-02 16:23:15 2020-02-12 16:23:15
1  5.587422e   2019-02-25 18:33:24 2019-02-25 18:33:24

print(df.dtypes)

Ref_ID                object
Date_Time             object
fixed_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```